# Prevent Xcode from creating NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN and NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END on new headers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header-files, xcode10, objective-c-nullability

I've updated Xcode and since updating I've been getting `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` macros around every new header file for every new class that I create.

I know what it does, but I'm not interested in nullability annotations it and it causes unnecessary warnings when I try to set some properties to `nil` in my app (which are perfectly okay to set to `nil`).

How do I prevent Xcode from creating these every time I create a new file? (other than the obvious: deleting them individually)

Comment: Yea, this feels like the continuing attack on ObjC by the change happy Swift community... who never seemed to understand the power of Nil in the first place... And still think Optionals make things safer..  sigh.   :-\

Comment: why not just remove those lines :)

Comment: @mgyky that's what I do. but as I create more and more files I tend to forget to remove, and it looks much more messy to the eye when trying to find something

Comment: @eric Optionals dont make things safer but non-optionals do. The real power of optionals is the ability to say that something will never be `nil`. Its actually an improvement for ObjC, too.

Comment: @Sulthan I totally get that, thank you for responding. The ability to enforce non-null was a good addition. But, it should be kept as an option; this change requires a lot of typing to specify non-null, when ObjC is built around nil objects being safe and clean, esp if you have your mindset tuned for that. The only nil crashes are around Apple's API (which I have long ago wrapped in a safer category). The issue I have is trying to shoehorn Swift "thinking" into ObjC, just because the script kiddies don't get it.

Comment: @eric The thinking is actually the same for both ObjC and Swift. The problematic part is that `nil` don't crash in Objective-C (unless you use them in unexpected places, e.g. adding `nil` to a `NSArray`) but they still hide errors ("my method is not being called"). Nil-awareness is helpful for Objective-C too.

Comment: @Sulthan nil awareness is absolutly critical, Young Apple folks, and their APIs don't get it, and are the ones at fault with Apple related nil issues. It is important to understand that nil objects/values are not the problem. Bad/Lazy devs are the problem, it's just that now they are lazy with force unwraps. Nil is not bad, it's really quite useful and powerful when done correctly, it doesn't hide anything, bad code hides things. That is true of any language. To those who don't understand Nil or force unwrap issues, it is bad. Enforcing Swift on ObjC is bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this](https://medium.com/@dima.cheverda/xcode-9-templates-596e2ed85609) and [this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/creating-custom-xcode-project-templates/) arcticles I was able to create custom template to get rid of `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL*` macros.

Excerpt from the first arcticle:

> Location
>
> These user-defined templates are located in
>   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Template. If such folder is
>   missing you can create it yourself and Xcode will be linked to it upon
>   reopening. Also you can group them into subfolders inside that folder.
>   For example, ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Template/Custom
>   Templates and Xcode will render those groups properly when creating a
>   new file.
>
> Template Setup
>
> Each template is a folder with .xctemplate extension. That folder
>   contains file templates and resources that will be populated and added
>   to a project and configuration TemplateInfo.plist.
>
> All template settings and fields that user can fill in during template
>   creation are defined in TemplateInfo.plist.

- create path as follows:

  `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Source/My Awesome
  Template.xctemplate`
- go to
  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File
  Templates/Source/Cocoa Touch Class.xctemplate`
- copy `TemplateIcon.png`, `TemplateIcon@2x.png` and
  `TemplateInfo.plist` to our `My Awesome Template.xctemplate` folder. You can omit copying icons if you do not need them in browser or use your own.
- copy `NSObjectObjective-C and NSObjectSwift` folders to be able to create both Obj C and Swift files.
- edit `___FILEBASENAME___.h`, `___FILEBASENAME___.m`, `___FILEBASENAME___.swift`, for example put your macros or in our case delete surrounding `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL*` macros
- now you are able to find your template in file creation browser on the very top
- Profit!

Comment: Wow, that was much extensive than I've expected!

Answer (score 2):

I found a best way:

1. go to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Source/Cocoa Touch Class.xctemplate/NSObjectObjective-C`
2. copy `___FILEBASENAME___.h` to anywhere
3. open and delete `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END`
4. Finally replace the original file and enter System password